# Verificando conexão com a internet com o phonegap

Tags: apache-cordova

Peguei este modelo do site do Phonegap e mesmo assim ele não emite um alerta mostrando o estado da conexão.
Quero que ao abrir o InAppBrowser que estou criando ele mostre se esta conectado na internet via 3g ou wifi e se não estiver ele emita um alerta avisando o usuário.

Exemplo: [Exemplo retirado do site do Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection_accessing_the_feature)

Ele não emite o alerta avisando o estado da conexão, como fazer isso?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>navigator.connection.type Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
    }

    function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>A dialog box will report the network state.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: como está seu código?

Comment: Math, esta do jeitinho que esta no site mesmo, nest elink ai...Eu só copiei e colei na aplicação, rodei ele no Eclipse emulando no smartphone conetado na internet e enão emite alerta algum.

Comment: Ajudaria se você colocasse ele aqui direto no corpo da sua pergunta, nem sempre as pessoas clicam no link para ver ou o link possui muito mais informação do que o necessário.

Comment: Eu sou novato aqui Math, não coloquei o código, por não saber colocar mesmo...Você me ajuda? Como faço para colocar um código HTML aqui na questão?

Comment: Clica em editar, copia e cola ele na sua pergunta, em seguida você seleciona seu código e clica no ícone `{}` (amostra de código), se estiver com dificuldades a gente conserta, mas tenta ae.

Comment: Pronto, esta ai o código.

Comment: Para verificar conexão internet, pode-se usar um Ping.

Comment: Na documentação diz que antes da versão 2.2.0, o objeto `connection` estava em `navigator.network.connection`... talvez seja isso.

Comment: Miguel, este exemplo ja foi retirado da versão 3.0, o site é bem organizado e contem um exemplo para cada versão...Estou usando a versão 3.0 e peguei o exemplo da versão 3.0, não teria porque não funcionar, esse site da Phonegap é muito zuado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifiquei seu código e tudo funciona de forma normal, faça o seguinte altere a função onDeviceReady para a seguinte

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("Device Ready");
        checkConnection();
    }
```

E verifique se alguma mensagem aparece na tela, caso não aparecer nada o problema deve estar ocorrendo antes mesmo do função de verificar a conexão.
Caso for o caso utilize o adb  para verificar os logs do Cordova.

Para isso abra o terminal e digite o seguite comando.
 **adb logcat "*:S CordovaLog:* Cordova:*"**